# Garden Grass/Lawn Mould Identification

Tags: identification, lawn, grass, mold

We have a standard grass lawn and in true British style got a paddling pool out a month too early. The pool got infested with mosquito larvae so we drained it (not into the garden) and got rid of the pool.

When we removed it we found that mould(?) had grown where the pool had been. It's definitely got two different areas of colour. After a couple of days these holes also appeared, I'm assuming it could be from birds. Any idea what this is and what we should do?[image: normal grass at the bottom, outer and inner mould]

Comment: cut it out, lay new sod..

Answer (score 3):

Nothing should be left in contact with a lawn for longer than a day or two at most, left for a week or three, this is what happens if you do, particularly during cool weather and very cool nights. It looks like the grey area in the middle is actually dead, but the browner ring round the outside may have some life in it still. Even so, it's best to cut the whole area of turf out and replace it with new, though care is needed to ensure the turf is at the same level as the rest of the grass. Harder still, you could remove it, turn it over, level the area, and seed it - but you'd need some extra topsoil to skim over the top to get it flush with the surrounding lawn. Even then, you usually find it sinks and ends up lower than the rest, or sometimes higher, its very hard to get it right.